# Getting diagnostic/debugging information from iOS app

Tags: ios, debugging, diagnostics

Users always email us with questions about in-app purchases, crashes and other odd behavior and it's like pulling teeth to get useful information from them about the state of their app.

What i'd like to do is create a single button somewhere that dumps a bunch of app state, logs and some information about which purchases they've made.

My question is, is Apple going to allow this type of built-in utility? It seems incredibly useful which is why I have a feeling they'll reject it upon review.

Does anyone already have an app that does something similar? Do you have any suggestions about what's allowed, what's not allow and if there are any utilities that made the implementation easier?

Comment: We do use firebase for crashes and analytics. That's great for fixing trending crashes and what-not, but it's not helpful when one specific user emails us looking for help. I need something that lets me see exactly what's going on with their specific instance and is easy for them to access without long complicated instructions.

Comment: We use something that at a high level revolves around having a logger output to a file and then that file can be emailed to anyone. One key piece is the logger must be activated, otherwise you will force all your users to output to a file. This is locked behind a specific user interaction (think NES cheat codes) and can be communicated to a user to send. It just becomes an issue of ensuring you log items of interest in resolving the issue.